# Arduino Bluetooth control code executes twice

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, arduino-c++

I am using the Arduino Bluetooth Controller app combined with a HC-06, and configured the app to send an 'A' to the serial monitor once you press a button, and a '0' when you let go of the button. The goal is to keep the servo's moving until you let go of the button. This works, except for when you only tap the button quickly; the code always executes twice. This is a problem, since it is important in this case to be able to do only a single movement. What can I change in the code to make sure the code only executes once?

Thanks in advance.

The code below works as intended, except for the case where you want the code in the while-loop to only execute once by tapping the button and letting go immediately.
I have already tried to increase the delay after the last `cha = Serial.read();` but this did not help.

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo servo1U;
Servo servo1L;
Servo servo2U;
Servo servo2L;
Servo servo3U;
Servo servo3L;
Servo servo4U;
Servo servo4L;
 
int neutral = 90;

int front_back = 0; //1U is omgekeerd, dus 180 - front_back
int front_right = 0; //1U is omgekeerd, dus 180 - front_right
int front_left = 180;

int back_forward = 180; //4U is omgekeerd, dus 180 - back_forward
int back_right = 180; //4U is omgekeerd, dus 180 - back_right
int back_left = 0;

int up = 90; //2L en 4L zijn omgekeerd, dus 180 - up
int down = 170; //2L en 4L zijn omgekeerd dus 180 - down

int small_right = 70;
int small_left = 110;

int state = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

servo1U.attach(9);
servo1L.attach(2);
servo2U.attach(3);
servo2L.attach(4);
servo3U.attach(5);
servo3L.attach(6);
servo4U.attach(7);
servo4L.attach(8);

  servo1U.write(neutral);
  servo2U.write(neutral);
  servo3U.write(back_forward);
  servo4U.write(180 - back_forward);

  servo1L.write(down);
  servo2L.write(180 - down);
  servo3L.write(down);
  servo4L.write(180 - down);


}

char cha;

void loop() {
if (Serial.available() > 0)
{
  cha = Serial.read();
  delay(5);
  
  if (cha == 'A'){ //Up arrow button on phone
  while (cha != '0'){

  delay(500);

  servo1U.write(180 - front_back);
  servo2U.write(front_back);
  servo3U.write(neutral);
  servo4U.write(neutral);

  delay(500);
   
  servo1L.write(up);
  servo2L.write(180 - up);
  servo3L.write(up);
  servo4L.write(180 - up);
    
  delay(500);

  servo1U.write(neutral);
  servo2U.write(neutral);
  servo3U.write(back_forward);
  servo4U.write(180 - back_forward);

  delay(500);

  servo1L.write(down);
  servo2L.write(180 - down);
  servo3L.write(down);
  servo4L.write(180 - down);
  
  cha = Serial.read();
  delay(500);
  }}
}
}
```

Comment: You oress the button in the app, right?

Comment: Yes, I press it once, but the servo's repeat the movement twice.

Comment: Are you sure the app only sends one character in that case?

Comment: Yes, I have also tried to put the characters in the serial monitor from the laptop directly, and it gives the same problem, so the problem is not in the app but in the code

Comment: yeah, your code is quite complex wit multiple nested loops, I don't believe these are needed

Comment: Do you know of a way to achieve what I want without these nested loops?

Comment: I just edited my answer to include another solution

Answer (score 0):

I was a bit confused by your nested loops so I changed it a bit and this should do the exact same thing (untested):

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo servo1U;
Servo servo1L;
Servo servo2U;
Servo servo2L;
Servo servo3U;
Servo servo3L;
Servo servo4U;
Servo servo4L;
 
int neutral = 90;

int front_back = 0; //1U is omgekeerd, dus 180 - front_back
int front_right = 0; //1U is omgekeerd, dus 180 - front_right
int front_left = 180;

int back_forward = 180; //4U is omgekeerd, dus 180 - back_forward
int back_right = 180; //4U is omgekeerd, dus 180 - back_right
int back_left = 0;

int up = 90; //2L en 4L zijn omgekeerd, dus 180 - up
int down = 170; //2L en 4L zijn omgekeerd dus 180 - down

int small_right = 70;
int small_left = 110;

int state = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  servo1U.attach(9);
  servo1L.attach(2);
  servo2U.attach(3);
  servo2L.attach(4);
  servo3U.attach(5);
  servo3L.attach(6);
  servo4U.attach(7);
  servo4L.attach(8);

  servo1U.write(neutral);
  servo2U.write(neutral);
  servo3U.write(back_forward);
  servo4U.write(180 - back_forward);

  servo1L.write(down);
  servo2L.write(180 - down);
  servo3L.write(down);
  servo4L.write(180 - down);


}

char lastCharacter;

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    lastCharacter = Serial.read();
    delay(5);
  }
  
  if (lastCharacter == 'A') //Up arrow button on phone
  {

    delay(500);

    servo1U.write(180 - front_back);
    servo2U.write(front_back);
    servo3U.write(neutral);
    servo4U.write(neutral);

    delay(500);
    
    servo1L.write(up);
    servo2L.write(180 - up);
    servo3L.write(up);
    servo4L.write(180 - up);
      
    delay(500);

    servo1U.write(neutral);
    servo2U.write(neutral);
    servo3U.write(back_forward);
    servo4U.write(180 - back_forward);

    delay(500);

    servo1L.write(down);
    servo2L.write(180 - down);
    servo3L.write(down);
    servo4L.write(180 - down);

    delay(500);
  }
}
```

Not sure if this already fixes your problem, but I see a serious flaw remaining:

The current state of the button via serial communication is only checked once your servo movement is done. So now if you send multiple characters while the servo is still moving they are "saved" and will be read one after another. For example:

1. You send A and the motor starts moving
2. You send 0
3. You send A
4. You send 0
5. The motor is done moving
6. The next character to read is 0, no movement happens
7. The next character is a A, motor starts moving
   ...

**Edit:**

The mentioned remaining problem should get fixed by replacing

```
  if (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    lastCharacter = Serial.read();
    delay(5);
  }
```

with

```
  while (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    lastCharacter = Serial.read();
    delay(5);
  }
```

This way all characters that where send during one loop are read and only the last character will be used. I'm not sure if the `delay` is still needed in that case